# OpenGL GLFW, triangle not rendering

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glfw, vao

I've been trying to render a triangle on macOS but it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

void OnError(int errorCode, const char* msg){
    throw std::runtime_error(msg);
}

int main(){
    glfwSetErrorCallback(OnError);
    if (!glfwInit()){
        throw std::runtime_error("glfwInit failed");
    }
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(512, 512, "Title", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window){
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK){
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);

    float points[] = {
        0.0, 0.5, 0.0,
        -0.5, -0.5, 0.0,
        0.5, -0.5, 0.0
    };

    GLuint vbo = 0;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(points), points, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLuint vao = 0;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);

    const char* vertex_shader =
    "#version 410\n"
    "in vec3 vp;"
    "void main(){"
    " gl_Position = vec4(vp, 1.0);"
    " };";

    GLuint vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vs, 1, &vertex_shader, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vs);

    const char* fragment_shader =
    "#version 410\n"
    "out vec4 frag_colour;"
    "void main(){"
    " frag_colour = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);"
    " };";

    GLuint fs = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fs, 1, &fragment_shader, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fs);

    GLuint shader_program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shader_program, fs);
    glAttachShader(shader_program, vs);
    glLinkProgram(shader_program);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){
        //glViewport(0, 0, 512, 512);
        //glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glUseProgram(shader_program);
        glBindVertexArray(vao);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        glfwPollEvents();
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you `glDisableVertexAttribArray(0)`. You've to enable it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Vertex array object name has to be generated by [`glGenVertexArrays`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGenVertexArrays.xhtml) rather than [`glGenBuffers`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGenBuffers.xhtml):

<s>`glGenBuffers(1, &vao);`</s>

```cpp
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
```

---

State vertex array specification and the enable state is stored in the vertex array object. Create the object name and bind (create) the vertex array object. Then the vertex arrays can be specified and enabled:

```cpp
GLuint vao = 0;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
```

It is sufficient to bind the vertex array object, before the geometry is drawn:

```cpp
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glUseProgram(shader_program);

    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}
```

Note, in your application a core profile [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context) is created (`GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE`). This causes that the default vertex array object (0) is not valid.
Instructions like [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) and [`glEnableVertexAttribArray`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glEnableVertexAttribArray.xhtml) change the state of the vertex array object. If no named vertex array object is bound when this functions are called, this causes an *INVALID_OPERATION* error.

---

Furthermore, you've created a 3.2 core profile OpneGL context. The GLSL version which corresponds to OpenGL 3.2 is 1.50.
Change the version specification in the vertex and fragment shader:

<s>`#version 410`</s>

```c
#version 150
```

---

The final triangle:

[image]

---

I recommend to check if the shader compilation succeeded and if the program object linked successfully.

If the compiling of a shader succeeded can be checked by [`glGetShaderiv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetShader.xhtml) and the parameter `GL_COMPILE_STATUS`. e.g.:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
```

```cpp
bool CompileStatus( GLuint shader )
{
    GLint status = GL_TRUE;
    glGetShaderiv( shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status );
    if (status == GL_FALSE)
    {
        GLint logLen;
        glGetShaderiv( shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLen );
        std::vector< char >log( logLen );
        GLsizei written;
        glGetShaderInfoLog( shader, logLen, &written, log.data() );
        std::cout << "compile error:" << std::endl << log.data() << std::endl;
    }
    return status != GL_FALSE;
}
```

If the linking of a program was successful can be checked by [`glGetProgramiv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetProgram.xhtml) and the parameter `GL_LINK_STATUS`. e.g.:

```cpp
bool LinkStatus( GLuint program )
{
    GLint status = GL_TRUE;
    glGetProgramiv( program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status );
    if (status == GL_FALSE)
    {
        GLint logLen;
        glGetProgramiv( program, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLen );
        std::vector< char >log( logLen );
        GLsizei written;
        glGetProgramInfoLog( program, logLen, &written, log.data() );
        std::cout << "link error:" << std::endl << log.data() << std::endl;
    }
    return status != GL_FALSE;
}
```

Call the functions after compiling the shaders, respectively linking the program:

```cpp
GLuint vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
glShaderSource(vs, 1, &vertex_shader, NULL);
glCompileShader(vs);
CompileStatus(vs);

GLuint fs = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
glShaderSource(fs, 1, &fragment_shader, NULL);
glCompileShader(fs);
CompileStatus(fs);

GLuint shader_program = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(shader_program, fs);
glAttachShader(shader_program, vs);
glLinkProgram(shader_program);
LinkStatus(shader_program);
```

Comment: Thanks, that was probably part of the problem. I still can't get it to work tough.

Comment: Ok, I probably misunderstood what you meant. Here is my current code: https://pastebin.com/SSPJgVSe

Comment: Oh, sorry, it still doesn't work tough. what am I doing wrong? https://pastebin.com/7TULZLfr

Comment: @Theelf111 Your hardaware can not deal with `#version 410`. Change to `#version 150`. See the answer.

Comment: I fixed it, the problems were the ";" after the "}" in the shader code.